# How to get local time date instead UTC time in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I want to get variable to save image name format using the date.

I use this following code.

`const time = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g, '');`

My expected variable is `20220629`. Because my local time is June 29, 2022.

But, the result variable is `20220628`. I think this result time using UTC time.

---

**Update:**

I try to using JS method like `toLocalDateString()` and get local time.

`const time = new Date().toLocaleDateString().replaceAll('/', '');`

But the result is `29062022` not `20220629`.

Can anyone help me how to convert into localtime? Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting the expected variable

Comment: The return from *toLocaleDateString* is implementation dependent and (where no language is passed) based on the host default language, so you should at least specify that. Consider `time.toLocaleDateString('en-CA').replaceAll('-','')`. *toLocale\** methods are not intended to provide exact formats, so if it really matters, format it manually yourself (similar to [anthonyB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72794613/257182)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date functions rely a lot on system settings to get your local date and time. If you're in the U.S. that happens to be month/day/year.

You simply need to deconstruct it to get what you're looking for. The below code will get it in the order you're looking for (and account for the month being 0-indexed):

```
const time = new Date()

const time2 = '' + time.getFullYear() + (time.getMonth() + 1) + time.getDate().toString().padStart(2,'0')
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: It doesn't pad single digit months and days. Consider `\`${time.getFullYear()}${String(time.getMonth()+1).padStart(2,'0')}${String(time.getDate()).padStart(2,'0')}\`` or even `time.toLocaleDateString('en-CA').replaceAll('-','')`. ;-)

Comment: Right. You'd have to do some additional manipulation. something like this `.toString().padStart(2,'0')` I'll edit the answer.